# Cesium pinBuilder with remote URL

Tags: cesium

Does anyone have an example of using the Cesium pinBuilder with a remote URL?  All the examples I have seen use local assets (with `buildModuleUrl()`)

This is what I'm trying:

```js
var pinBuilder = new Cesium.PinBuilder();
var url = 'https://hearmynamefiles.storage.googleapis.com/gp/220px-Jeanine_anez2.png';

var leaderPin = Cesium.when(pinBuilder.fromUrl(url, Cesium.Color.GREEN, 96), function(canvas) {
    return viewer.entities.add({
        name : 'Anez',
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1705217, 39.921786),
        billboard : {
            image : canvas.toDataURL(),
            verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
        }
    });
});
```

This same URL works fine to create a billboard, so I must be doing something wrong when I try to create a pin with it, but I'm not getting any errors.